# jQuery - Clear cloned form value

Tags: jquery

In the code below, when I try to set the val() to an empty string: val(""), the code breaks and the form is not appended. But as it is, when the form is appended, the input value of the form is cloned, which is what I don't want, and been trying to remove with the val(""), to no avail. I tried looking for similar questions but I don't think they represent my scenario.

Html:

```
<form id="postcomment" method="post" action="">
    <!-- form displayed here -->

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" /></p>
</form>

<ul id="commenters">
    <li id="user_id">
        <p class="poster">SomeUser - time_post_submitted</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="" class="reply">reply</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#commenters").on("click", ".reply", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $("#postcomment").clone();
            form.find('.parent').val($(this).parent().parent().attr('user_id'));
            $(this).parent().append(form);
        });
    });
```

EDIT: http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/django-threaded-comments/

Adding the link for clarity. I followed the example down to the letter, but I'm presented with the problem I'm trying to solve here

Comment: form.find('.parent') will return null. Do you have an element with class parent with in your form?

Comment: @codehx I just double checked, and I there's no element with parent class in the form.

Comment: So that is why `form.find('.parent').val($(this).parent().parent().attr('user_id'));` fails

Comment: @codehx The thing is, when I remove the .parent  and two parent() the form doesn't append at all

Comment: You have to provide a complete example in question itself of what you are looking for

Comment: I want a facebook-style commenting system. When user clicks enter/submit post, the content is posted, and a new form is appended. In my case, the new form is appended but with the old value of the input, not a clean new one... Ya dig?

Comment: @AnthonyO.: That doesn't cover it. Your code is relying on an element with class `parent`. Your markup doesn't have one. So the question cannot be usefully answered.

Comment: @codehx: *"form.find('.parent') will return null."* Not null, but an empty set, yes.

Comment: If you trying to reset the original form element as well,             $("form#postcomment")[0].reset(); does the trick. check http://jsbin.com/zejuma/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: problem is when I remove the ".parent" from find(".parent") the reply functionality breaks. But as you stated there's no .parent in the html, but somehow removing it breaks the code. Do you have a suggestion for either a) replacing the find(".parent") with relevant code, b) playing with the val() and forcing a val("")?. Sorry for the hassle, but I'm really a beginner in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zejuma/1/edit?html,js,output)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#commenters").on("click", ".reply", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // in case you want to clear the original form as well
            $("form#postcomment")[0].reset();
            var form = $("#postcomment").clone();
            form[0].reset();
            form.find('.parent').val($(this).parent().parent().attr('user_id'));
            $(this).parent().append(form);
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

```
$(function() {
  $("body").on("click submit", "input[type='submit']", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this).parent().find("input[type='text']");
    var comment = $el.val();
    var temp = '<li id="user_id"><p class="poster"></p>'+comment+'<br><a href="" class="reply">reply</a></li>';
    if($($(this).parent()[0]).hasClass('replyform')) {
       $(this).parent().parent().append(temp);
    } else {
    $("ul#commenters").append(temp);  
    }
    $el.val("");
    $("ul#commenters .reply").show();
    $("ul#commenters form").hide();
  });

   $("#commenters").on("click", ".reply", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // in case you want to clear the original form as well
     $(this).hide();
            $("form#postcomment")[0].reset();
            var form = $("#postcomment").clone();
            $(form[0]).addClass("replyform");
            form[0].reset();
            form.find('.parent').val($(this).parent().parent().attr('user_id'));
            $(this).parent().append(form);
        });

});
```

HTML :

```
<form id="postcomment" method="post" action="">

        <input type="text" name="formva">
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
<ul id="commenters">

</ul>
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zejuma/2/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it's still not working. The jsbin demo gives me a forbidden error(403) too. At this point, I don't know what to think to be honest. I really need this functionality, and don't want to use disqus as I find it ugly

Comment: You need to click on reply button. Hope you clicked on post button

Comment: The event is bound to the reply button in your code

Comment: http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/django-threaded-comments/

the link shows what I'm trying to accomplish, but following that tutorial leads to the problem I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: Updated based on comments :)

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. Thank you! You saved my (coding) life. I tried to upvote but apparently it says I need 15 rep points... ahah it sucks to be a newcomer

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)  function?

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#commenters").on("click", ".reply", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var $form = $("#postcomment");
      $form[0].reset();

      $form.find('.parent').val($(this).parent().parent().attr('user_id'));
      $(this).parent().append($form.clone());
   });
});
```

Comment: Sadly, still not working. I guess this is the part where I start to pull my hair out

Comment: @Antony O. sorry. little mistake in handler. I edit my answer. And 
check  this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwp7d4og/)